# How to force load every element on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, vba

This page have limited number of devices with class ***col-md-4***. When you reach specific page level then another devices are loaded.[enter link description here](https://www.technomarket.bg/telefoni)

Is there a way to make a url which will show me all devices without the need to scroll to see them? 
I need this for VBA script which will make a list with devices url links.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is this specific page level ? lvl 5 lvl 20 are we in a game?

Comment: what you seek to build is called a crawler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is calling url

```
https://www.technomarket.bg/product/filter?filter_form%5Bsort%5D=default&filter_form%5Bprice%5D%5Bmin%5D=39&filter_form%5Bprice%5D%5Bmax%5D=2099&filter_form%5Bspec_gsm_display%5D%5Bmin%5D=&filter_form%5Bspec_gsm_display%5D%5Bmax%5D=&filter_form%5Bspec_gsm_battery%5D%5Bmin%5D=&filter_form%5Bspec_gsm_battery%5D%5Bmax%5D=&filter_key=%2Ftelefoni%7Cstatic%7Cstatic&from=80&size=20
```

where you can set size to any arbitrary size of products you need
or you can use application like burpsuite to change size of products you need
in google chrome in network tab as google loading new stuff you can see xhr type request in you can see details on that
[image]

Comment: It is perfect. Thank you very much for the answer! :)

Can you teach me how you manage to  create this url?

Comment: you can go to developer mode in google chrome and in a network tab. any url is called will show there.

Comment: Yeah I check in Network tab, but there are only files and scripts that are loaded....

Comment: I edited my answer and added some more detail.checked it out